# How can I achieve having an UITableView set the insets of its cells without setting the inset on the entire table?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiedgeinsets

I have a `UITableViewCell` with content that extends to all of its edges. I use this cell in multiple tables with where it needs varying insets. (i.e. one table will have it inset from the left by 8 points, another will have it inset 20 points. I'd like to indent the cell in the parent `UITableView` code (maybe `cellForRow`?) without indenting the entire table.

This obviously sets it for the entire table, but I'd like to do it on a cell-by-cell basis as needed:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: -20)
```

This is having no effect:

```
tableViewCell.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: -20)
```

Nor is this working (even though it's on the cell itself):

```
override func layoutMarginsDidChange() {
    super.layoutMarginsDidChange()

    self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20 bottom: 0, right: -20)
}
```

Comment: Are your cells a custom UITableViewCell subclass? If so, you could just write the layout code in there.

Comment: @Connor Yes, I'm using a custom UITableViewCell subclass. However I can't write the code in there because the cell is used in different tables and the cell has no idea which table it's in.

Comment: so then, in your `cellForRow`, you're presumably passing in some object to configure your custom cell with right? I would expand that object (or pass in a second object) to include some variable that tells the cell whether or not to conditionally use this different layout.

Comment: @Connor Very valid point but as i mentioned, `override func layoutMarginsDidChange() {` on the cell seems to have no effect.

Comment: When `cellForRow` is called and you are creating your cells you should set it then on each individual cell before returning the cell to the UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you constrain to margins in the xib/storyboard. Then set the following on the `UITableViewCell`:

```
var topInset: CGFloat = 0
var leftInset: CGFloat = 0
var bottomInset: CGFloat = 0
var rightInset: CGFloat = 0

override func layoutMarginsDidChange() {
    super.layoutMarginsDidChange()
    self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
}
```

Then in the tableView `cellForRowAt`, use the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let browseTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BrowseTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BrowseTableViewCell

    browseTableViewCell.leftInset = 20
    browseTableViewCell.rightInset = 20
    // Top and bottom insets are not needed. They will default to 0.

    return browseTableViewCell
}
```