# How to add unique insets to specific UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` whose `insetsContentViewsToSafeArea` property is set to `false` - this makes the `tableView` span the width of the screen.

The amount and different types of cells are driven by the server, so there's no way of knowing the content of the `tableView`.

### What I'd like to to:

Assign unique insets to certain cells only.

I can't post a screenshot, so I'll try to make a quick doodle:

*These three cells are all in the same `UITableView`:*

|[This is one cell that goes edge-to-edge]|

|[Here's another one]|

|-----This cell needs its own insets-----|

### Question:

What's the best way to achieve this?

### What I've tried:

- [Overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760732/how-can-i-achieve-having-an-uitableview-set-the-insets-of-its-cells-without-sett) `layoutMarginsDidChange`
- Trying to add `layoutMargins` directly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath...`

Answer (score 0):

Create a UITableViewCell subclass for the cell with custom insets.

Then you have 2 options --

1. Add a subview to cell's contentView with constraints -- these will correspond to your desired insets. This view will act as your " pseudo contentView" (add cell content to it)
2. Play around with contentView's insets. (not sure if it'll work)

I hope this will get you started.

You can use the cell subclass for all cell cases too if you want -- with an enum style which you can set in cell for row.

```
enum Style {
 case edgeToEdge
 case withInset(inset: UIEdgeInset)
}

inside cell subclass

var insetStyle: Style = .edgeToEdge {
   didSet {
      //update the constraints of the pseudo content view
   }
}
```